# Does encrypting JWSs (Signed JWT) protect from finding the signing key?

Tags: security, jwt, jwe

One of the pros for using encrypted tokens is privacy - token content can't be read.

I was wandering if there are other pros. One specific thought relates to **signed token (JWS)**.

Can attacker, having many JSWs, find out the signing key? This is because the content of the signed key can be read and matched.

If the token is encrypted, this cannot be done, as the content cannot be read.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the attacker to find the signing key , he will have to break into either the issuing party's system or the receiver's system.

The JWS specification has the provision for Key ID or kid , which gives the receiver a hint of which key has been used to sign the Token . This is understandable since at any given point of time the system can have multiple valid keys for such purpose and appropriate kid will point to the right set of key used for signing .

So for any one to find out the signing key ( it's value ) he will need to break into either of the issuer or the receiver's system .

Alternately some also prefer to use the JSON Web Key URL ( jku ) which is another  header parameter and is an absolute URL that refers to a resource for a set of JSON-encoded public keys, one of which corresponds to the key that was used to sign the JWS.